# hadoop cluster high availability error couldn't find or load main class

Tags: centos-6, hadoop

```
[hduser@mn1 bin]$ ./hdfs zkfc -formatZK
Error: Could not find or load main class ”-Djava.library.path=”.home.hduser.2.3.0″.lib”
```

I did every step just like in this tutorial, TWICE. The error still the same though and I can't figure it out. Please help me!
Does the architecture of the OS matters with this package?
They were using 32-bit in the tutorial, while I'm using 64-bit.